# Conditional type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Let's imagine I have a function that I want to pass an argument to. My own condition type is based on the type of argument, but when I want to return the value based on interfaces, the function gives me an error.

This is the actual code:

```
interface IdLabel {
  id: number;
}

interface NameLabel {
  name: string;
}

type NameOrId<T extends string | number> = T extends number ? IdLabel : NameLabel;

function createLabel<T extends string | number>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  if (typeof idOrName === "number") {
    return {
      id: idOrName
    };
  } else {
    return {
      name: idOrName
    };
  }
}

const a = createLabel(1);
const b = createLabel("something");
```

You can see the error in this picture:

[image]

**this is the text error:**

```
Type '{ id: T & number; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.
Type '{ name: T; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.
```

Comment: Why not use overloads: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5QDcJAviSaJLIigDk4DCNjyFS5EMIg0AzmCigA5m04kYdEAjDAA9iGQIoEOJDEEAFJRr0m0AJQ0MF-G03bdBoybOjcVtIi8ooqTshCIq7uWjr6hsam5gH41ugA8lCRssgKSiDKyAA+tIzM4dmuxWhYKcRkFDDIlmAAngAOEHpNlJnZyAC8Q8gARHbMIw715OQmYHRQhpIz5DYUGVkyDeTsbDvIBHIoy7MQ84vTK7QyNL2bItvIuw2c6ggGCshwgz5J-uKWACMDjY7xAnxwP0SflclhGcj0IjAAAsVJM2EA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe I just want to test this code by conditional type. i think conditional type is more clear than overloads.

Comment: [Please consider replacing or supplementing images of code/errors with plain text versions when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz Sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a conditional type like `NameOrId<T>` depends on an unresolved type parameter like the `T` inside the body of `createLabel()`, the compiler *defers* evaluating it.  Such a type is essentially opaque to the compiler, and therefore it is generally unable to verify that a specific value like `{id: idOrName}` is assignable to it.

When you check `typeof idOrName`, [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) will narrow the apparent type of `idOrName`, but this *does not* narrow the type parameter `T` itself.  If `typeof idOrName === "string"`, `idOrName` is now known as being of type `string` (or `T & string`), but `T` is still possibly `string | number`, and is still an unresolved generic type parameter.

This is a known pain point of TypeScript.  There is an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), asking for some way to allow control flow analysis to verify assignability to unresolved conditional types, especially as the return value of a function like you want here.  Until and unless that issue is addressed, you'll have to work around it.

---

Workarounds:

Whenever you have a situation where you are certain that an expression `expr` is of type `Type` but the compiler is not, you can always use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler so: `expr as Type`, or, in cases where the compiler sees the type `expr` as completely unrelated to `Type`, you might have to write `expr as any as Type` or use some other intermediate assertion.

That would give you this:

```
function createLabelAssert<T extends string | number>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
    if (typeof idOrName === "number") {
        return {
            id: idOrName
        } as unknown as NameOrId<T>;
    } else {
        return {
            name: idOrName
        } as unknown as NameOrId<T>;
    }
}
```

This resolves the errors.  Note that by making an assertion, you are taking responsibility for type safety.  If you modified the `typeof idOrName === "number"` check to `typeof idOrName !== "number"`, there would still be no compiler error.  But you would be unhappy at runtime.

---

When you have a function whose return type can't be verified in the implementation, you could do the "moral equivalent" of a type assertion: an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with a single call signature.  Overload implementations are checked more loosely than regular functions, so you can get the same behavior as a type assertion without having to assert at each `return` line separately:

```
// call signature
function createLabel<T extends string | number>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T>;
// implementation
function createLabel(idOrName: string | number): NameOrId<string | number> {
    if (typeof idOrName === "number") {
        return {
            id: idOrName
        };
    } else {
        return {
            name: idOrName
        };
    }
}
```

The call signature is the same, but now the implementation signature is just a mapping from `string | number` to `IdLabel | NameLabel`.  Again, the compiler won't catch the problem where you check `typeof idOrName !== "number"` accidentally, so you need to be careful here too.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mNfPKnQAjAN2FWQDWcHWiib+RJOht5LlRGAABaqPasIA)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz Thank you so much for your help.